# Flex/AS3/XML: how to dynamically change XMLList used for Flex submenu?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex

Using actionscript 3, can someone give an example how I can dynamically change the submenu items below?

```
<fx:Declarations>
<fx:XMLList id="menuData" xmlns="">
    <menuitem label="Column A">
            <menuitem label="Item A.1"/>
            <menuitem label="Item A.2"/>
    </menuitem>
    <menuitem label="Column B">
            <menuitem id="ItemB1" label="B.1"/>
            <menuitem type="separator"/>
            <menuitem label="Item B.2" type="check"/>
            <menuitem label="Item B.3" type="check"/>
            <menuitem id="myId" label="Item B.4">
                <menuitem label="SubItem B.4.1"/>
                <menuitem label="SubItem B.4.2"/>
            </menuitem>
    </menuitem>
        ...
</fx:XMLList>
<fx:Declarations>
...
<mx:MenuBar dataProvider="{menuData}" .../>
```

For example, suppose we want to replace submenu items B.4.1 and B.4.2 with:

```
<menuitem label="SubItem abc"/>
<menuitem label="SubItem def"/>
<menuitem label="SubItem ghi"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the item by its label, or better, give it an id and use this to retreive it, and then [replace its children](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html#setChildren%28%29).

You can easily do this utilizing [E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html):

```
var item:XMLList = menuData..menuitem.(attribute('label') == "Item B.4");

var subItems:XML = 
    <items>
        <menuitem label="SubItem abc"/>
        <menuitem label="SubItem def"/>
        <menuitem label="SubItem ghi"/>
    </items>;

item.setChildren(subItems.menuitem);
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html for more information on this subject.

Comment: Thanks ndm, this is very much what I'm looking for. I've added an id above for Item B.4. How would I grab the item by it's Id as you suggest above? Would it be: `var item:XMLList = menuData..menuitem.(@id == 'myId')`? Do I need to make one of the variables bindable to make the change take place? Thanks

Comment: By simply exchanging the values in the E4X expression, ie replace `label` with `id`, and `Item B.4` with `myId`. I only suggested using an ID so that you can change the label without breaking the access expression.

Comment: No, you don't need to make anything bindable, the XMLList is already bound as a dataprodiver, and the MenuBar component will register changes made to it automatically.